# Ambiguous definition of operator() with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I compile this code with GCC (4.2.1 Apple build 5664)

```
#include <cstddef>

using std::size_t;

template <char I> struct index { };

struct a
{
    void operator()(size_t const &) { }
};

struct b
{
    template <char I>
    void operator()(index<I> const &) { }
};

struct c: public a, public b { };

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    c vc;
    vc(1);

    return 0;
}
```

and give me the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
main.cpp:22: error: request for member ‘operator()’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:14: error: candidates are: template<char I> void b::operator()(const index<I>&)
main.cpp:9:  error:                 void a::operator()(const size_t&)
```

I don't understand the reason why this code is ambiguous; the two methods have different signatures.

Comment: I'm surprised that Clang can compile your code, while GCC complains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify `c` this way:

```
struct c: public a, public b
{
    using a::operator();
    using b::operator();
};
```

C++ (prior to C++0x) is kind of awkward in inheriting functions: if you provide a function with the same name of a base class' function it hides base class ones.

It looks like also inheriting from two classes has the same problem.

// looking for the standard...

Comment: That is only the case if they have the same signature, which these functions do not.

Comment: @Zac Howland: not sure, you could be right, but GCC won't compile it otherwise. Maybe a GCC bug? Clang will compile without any issue OP's code...

Comment: @Zac Howland: hiding happens on name match not signature.

Comment: @peoro: this is different than derived class hiding base class method with same name. In that case there would've been no ambiguity and no error if `operator()(size_t const &)` would've been in `c` and it would not find a match if `operator()(index<I> const &)` would've been in `c`.

Comment: @peoro: speaking about the standard, in Draft N3225 section '10.2 Member name lookup' there's an example exactly like OPs.

Comment: @peoro Thank you. I didn't to read the standard, because I was sure that name hiding works with signature. But I can confirm, it works with name (section 3.3.10 of standard, I hope).

Answer (score 6):

Name resolution is done before overload resolution.
There is no `operator()` in `c` so the compiler goes looking for `operator()` in it's base classes and finds one in `a` and another in `b` making the name ambiguous (and no overload resolution takes place).

If you want to eliminate the name ambiguity you can call `a::operator()` explicitly: `vc.a::operator()(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Its ambiguous because you are passing in an integer constant that can (presumably) be casted to either a `std::size_t` or `index` types.  Change `main` to the following and it should resolve it:

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    c vc;
    vc(static_cast<std::size_t>(1));

    return 0;
}
```

With that said, it is highly likely that you shouldn't be using multiple inheritance here.

Comment: An integer can't be casted to a index type. And if you try to compile, it doesn't work.

Comment: @mattia:  You'll have to be more specific about the problem.  With what you've shown, the code above will work (obviously, you'd have to change the cast if you want the other operator).  @peoro:  `static_cast` does exactly what he is doing here - casting an integer to a specific type.

Comment: @mattia:  Try doing this instead of the inline `static_cast` then:  `std::size_t i = 1;  vc(i);`

Comment: @Zac Howland: I don't think that's the problem: as mattia.penati said, an integer cannot be casted to an `index`. Besides GCC will keep complaining with both of your solutions.

Comment: @Zac: to be able to static_cast you need a conversion function, but index doesn't have one. Maybe you are thinking of reinterpret_cast? Which would obviously not be appropriated in this case (an integer and an index object have different sizes...)

Comment: @Francesco:  You don't need a conversion function to static_cast an `integer` to a `std::size_t` (it already exists).  But peoro is correct, the primary problem actually isn't the cast but the name problem.  The casting problem won't be visible until `index` is a non-trivial class.  In general, this whole approach is very flawed though.

Comment: @Zac: sorry, I misread your answer. I was sure to have read static_cast to index, and not to size_t.