# How can I resolve a function call ambiguity when multiple base classes have a member function with the same name?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, member-functions, ambiguous-call

I have a basic question related to multiple inheritance in C++. If I have a code as shown below:

```
struct base1 {
   void start() { cout << "Inside base1"; }
};

struct base2 {
   void start() { cout << "Inside base2"; }
};

struct derived : base1, base2 { };

int main() {
  derived a;
  a.start();
}
```

which gives the following compilation error:

```
1>c:\mytest.cpp(41): error C2385: ambiguous access of 'start'
1>      could be the 'start' in base 'base1'
1>      or could be the 'start' in base 'base2'
```

Is there no way to be able to call function `start()` from a specific base class using a derived class object?

I don't know the use-case right now but.. still!

Comment: I shortened the snippet. No semantics were changed.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831759/ambiguous-definition-of-operator-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Rename the functions start1 and start2.

Comment: @JohnPaul not the same though; this one is about two base classes with an identical function, that one is about two base classes that have a function with the same name, but differing arguments.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
a.base1::start();

a.base2::start();
```

or if you want to use one specifically

```
class derived:public base1,public base2
{
public:
    using base1::start;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure!

```
a.base1::start();
```

or

```
a.base2::start();
```

Comment: Trying to understand - "if the inheritance were virtual, there would be no ambiguity". How is that?

Comment: @goldenmean: That hasn't been part of my answer for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, if we are in the case of NON-VIRTUAL inheritance:

you can:

1. use `static_cast<base1*>(a).start()`

or

2. override start() in derived

Btw - please note the diamond problem that can appear. In this case you might want to use virtual.