# Multiple specializations of the same template with different typenames in a single class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm implementing an observer pattern as a template, and wanted one class to have different listener types being attached. The problem is that it doesn't seem possible to use the same template in a single class multiple times with different types. As far as I understand it, it should be possible, because the method names would have different types anyway, so they should be mangled into a different names. However the error I get is not at linktime, but at compiletime, so I would like to know what I'm doing wrong or if this is not possible at all.

To demonstrate the problem I wrote a SSCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Comparator
{
public:
    Comparator(void) { mCounter = 0; };
    virtual ~Comparator(void) {};

    bool equals(T oFirst, T oSecond)
    {
        mCounter++;
        if(oFirst != oSecond)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    int getCounter(void)
    {
        return mCounter;
    }

private:
    int mCounter;
};

class TestClass :
    public Comparator<int>,
    public Comparator<void *>
{
public:
    TestClass(void) {};
    virtual ~TestClass(void) {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestClass t1;
    TestClass *t2 = &t1;
    TestClass *t3 = new TestClass();
    int v1 = 1;
    int v2 = 2;
    bool b = t1.equals(v1, v2);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << t1.equals(&t1, &t2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << t1.getCounter() << std::endl;

    delete t3;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with gcc (using Cx11 option) I get the following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in CPPMingW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|38|error: request for member 'equals' is ambiguous|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note: candidates are: bool Comparator<T>::equals(T, T) [with T = void*]|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note:                 bool Comparator<T>::equals(T, T) [with T = int]|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|38|error: expected primary-expression before 'int'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|38|error: expected ';' before 'int'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|39|error: request for member 'equals' is ambiguous|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note: candidates are: bool Comparator<T>::equals(T, T) [with T = void*]|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note:                 bool Comparator<T>::equals(T, T) [with T = int]|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|35|warning: unused variable 'v1' [-Wunused-variable]|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|36|warning: unused variable 'v2' [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

In this example I don't really see why it should be ambigous, because in both calls the datatype is well defined and totally different from the other template specialization. I would expect the errof from `getCounter()` because this is really not determinable.

Comment: Also, I think you meant for this: `t1.equals(t1, t2)` to be this: `t1.equals(&t1, t2)` (or possibly `t1.equals(t2, t3)`).

Comment: `equals()` doesn't use any information from the object, so could equally be `static`. Also, I don't see any reason why the classes should be polymorphic.

Comment: @dlf, yeah you are right. But since this is only a smaple it demonstrate the problem. That the code will not work is another problem, but beside the point. I fix it anyway.

Comment: @iavr, that's really beside the point., I'm not talking abouit OO modelling, I'm talking about a specific problem which is demonstrated by the SSCE.

Comment: @Devolus Sure, and if I had concentrated on the problem I would probably be the first to answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect `equals` from your base classes to participate in overload resolution as if they were both defined in your derived class, but unfortunately it doesn't work that way (I'm not sure why not).

You can either explicitly call the version of `equals` you want:

```
t1.Comparator<int>::equals(v1, v2);
```

Or you can add this in your derived class (public section):

```
using Comparator<int>::equals;
using Comparator<void*>::equals;
```

Which should allow the 2 equals functions from your base classes to do the standard overload resolution. You could also achieve the same thing by *writing* the 2 equals functions in the derived class and having each one call the appropriate base class `equals`.

Just to note: `Comparator<int>` and `Comparator<void*>` are entirely separate classes. They know nothing of eachother. This would behave the same if they were not templates but had different names as well.

Comment: Just another bit of info: the fact that `Comparator` is a template is immaterial. If you write two non-templated base classes named ComparatorInt and ComparatorVp, you get the exact same behavior. However, if both `equals()` are actually implemented in `TestClass` instead of base classes (or are implemented in the same base class), the ambiguity disappears. It would appear that acceptable name matches from two different base classes are considered equally good even if one fits the arguments better than the other.

Comment: "I'm not sure why not": Well, if it was the other way (base members were used by default), there would be no way to disable them and defined a fresh `equals` that is not overloaded with anything. But I would personally prefer them to be used by default (it's definitely more common) and the language had another way to disable them if needed (like `= delete`).

Comment: Thanks for the exaplanation. So this is actually a `multiple inheritance problem` and not really a template issue. Still, I would have expected the compiler to be able to determine the correct call, but at least I understand now the error message.

Comment: @Devolus Not just a multiple inheritance problem. Overload resolution also doesn't work if one of the `equals` was in the base and the other was in the derived.

Comment: @Dave, Thanks! Could you please explain the `using Comparator<int>::equals;` part a bit more, because I'm not sure I really understand what you mean by that and how to get the behaviour from the compiler overload resolution.

Comment: @Dave In that case (one `equals()` in derived, one in base), isn't the problem that the base class overload is hidden by the derived one?

Comment: @iavr I agree with the sentiment (and using `= delete` to hide base class methods) but in this particular case the derived class doesn't attempt to hide anything, so it seems reasonable that they could overload eachother.

Comment: @dlf Yes indeed. But still, they don't participate in overload resolution by default.

Comment: @Devolus Think of `using Comparator<int>::equals` as shorthand for defining this method in `TestClass`: `bool equals(int l, int r){ return Comparator<int>::equals(l, r); }`. It just instructs the compiler to treat your base class's method as your own

Comment: @Dave, I see what you mean. At first I didin't like it, but thinking a b it more about this, I can see some advatnages to this now.

Comment: @Dave [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4832166/3549027) seems apropos (though it doesn't provide a standard quote to back up its assertion).